# setState in redux from fetch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new in redux. Is it the right way to setState?

How do I setState **forYou** after fetching data from server?

here is my code:

```
const initialState={
    forYou: [],
}


function rootReducer(state=initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case 'forYou':
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/forYou/'
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }).then(res=>res.json().then(result=>{
                var forYou = result
                return{
                    ...state,
                    forYou: forYou
                }
            }))
        
        break


        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer
```

So, what i should change?

Comment: No, your `forYou` case completes and `rootReducer` returns `undefined` before your `fetch` callback runs. Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: It is a better practise to move all the fetch calls to a middleware like redux-saga or redux-thunk etc.. From there you can pass details of response via  a callback function and then dispatch an action to set state.

Answer (score 2):

Your reducer must return new state, synchronously, which you're not doing.

The return in your `then` isn't the return value from your reducer function, it's the return value from the `then` function, which is ultimately what the `fetch` call chain will resolve to.

Returning the resolved value (e.g. `return fetch(...)`) won't work either, because fetch is asynchronous. Its return value is a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not the resolved state.

There are off-the-shelf libraries like [saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) and [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to help with this sort of thing, but the basic idea is the same: Move your asynchronous code out to a separate function and have it dispatch state transitions:

```js
// pseudo-code, not an actual implementation
async function forYou () {
  // transition into a loading state; display a spinner or whatever
  dispatch({ type: LOADING, value: true });

  // await the fetch
  const result = await fetch(...);

  // once the fetch completes, dispatch an action with the result
  dispatch({ type: FOR_YOU, value: result })

  // and transition out of the loading state
  dispatch({ type: LOADING, value: false })
}
```